# Header already sent error - Sometime with some browser

Tags: codeigniter

> Severity: Warning
>
> Message: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /hermes/bosoraweb095/b1793/ipg.orangetechcomnp/projects/Himalayan/application?/controllers/activity.php:1)
>
> Filename: libraries/Session.php
>
> Line Number: 416

The most probable cause is because of following things as far as I have researched:

1. Whitespace or space before
2. UTF 08 problem with File Editor - I Checked and that is not a problem.
3. Use of echoes - I have not used echo, and however the error is in line number 1.

Note - I tried with Opera, Chrome and Firefox and the strange thing was the error is sometimes shown in opera, sometimes in chrome, sometimes in Firefox, sometime in all.

When it works well on Chorome, error is displayed in Firefox. When I refresh, again the error message is show.

My CodeIgnitor Code:

```
    <?php
    class activity extends CI_Controller {
    const VIEW_FOLDER = 'activity/activity';    
    public function __construct(){
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->model('activity_model');
    $this->load->model('testimonial_model');
     }
function index()
{

    $id=$this->uri->segment(3);
    $data= array(

        'activity_list'=> $this->activity_model->get_activity_id($id),
        'recent_list'=> $this->activity_model->get_recent(),
        'popular_list'=> $this->activity_model->get_popular(),
        'testimonial_list'=> $this->testimonial_model->get_testimonial(),
        'category_list'=> $this->activity_model->get_category_id($id),
        //'pagination' => $this->pagination->create_links(),            
        );

        $this->load->view('includes_frontend/header');
        $this->load->view('includes_frontend/menu');
        $this->load->view('activity/detail_activity',$data);    
        $this->load->view('includes_frontend/footer',$data);

}

function main_activity(){


 //pagination settings
    $config['per_page'] = 8;
    $config['uri_segment']=4;
    $config['base_url'] = base_url().'activity/main_activity';
    $config['use_page_numbers'] = TRUE;
    $config['num_links'] = 20;
    $config['full_tag_open'] = '<ul class="pagination">';
    $config['full_tag_close'] = '</ul>';
    $config['num_tag_open'] = '<li>';
    $config['num_tag_close'] = '</li>';
    $config['cur_tag_open'] = '<li class="active"><a>';
    $config['cur_tag_close'] = '</a></li>';
    $config['next_tag_open'] = '<li>';
    $config['next_tag_close'] = '</li>';
    $config['prev_tag_open'] = '<li>';
    $config['prev_tag_close'] = '</li>';

    //limit end
    $page = $this->uri->segment(4);

    //math to get the initial record to be select in the database
    $limit_end = ($page * $config['per_page']) - $config['per_page'];
    if ($limit_end < 0){
        $limit_end = 0;
    } 


        //fetch sql data into arrays
        $data['count_activity']= $this->activity_model->count_activity();
       // $data['activity'] = $this->activity_model->get_activity($config['per_page'],$limit_end);        
        $config['total_rows'] = $data['count_activity'];



        $data= array(

        'activity_list'=> $this->activity_model->get_activity($config['per_page'], $limit_end),
        //'pagination' => $this->pagination->create_links(),
        'testimonial_list'=> $this->testimonial_model->get_testimonial(),

        );$this->pagination->initialize($config);
        $this->load->view('includes_frontend/header');
        $this->load->view('includes_frontend/menu');
        $this->load->view('activity/activity',$data);   
        $this->load->view('includes_frontend/footer',$data);    

    }
```

}

Comment: You see that white space at the beginning of your file?

Comment: There is no whitespace...

Comment: As others have noted - your posted code example appears to have a number of spaces before the <?php on the first line. Is that indentation you added when you posted the question on here or are those spaces/tabs actually there on the first line of the code you are actually using?

Comment: The Error Message even states "rather loudly" that the output starts at line 1.

Comment: The spaces are only here in the code. They are fine in my controller.

Comment: Are you using database sessions? The error is coming from `sess_destroy()` function of the `Session` library. I reckon the app is trying to header a database error

Answer (score 0):

This is going to be a white space issue. Check the controller and models to see if there is some whitespace at the start and end of the files.

Comment: I dont know, However I found out that when I go through the link directly, there is an error but when I visit the link through a hyperlink in my homepage, the problem is not there.